# How does "Stream" in java8 work?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream, lambda-calculus

I'm ask for the reason or the principle.

I found that most methods of the interface "Stream" in Java8 are not declared as "default",so they have no method body.For example：

boolean anyMatch(Predicate predicate);

boolean allMatch(Predicate predicate);

Stream map(Function mapper);

As you can see in the source file Stream.java.

But these methods without bodies seem to be able to be executed in java programs.

Do you know why?

Thank you.

Comment: because the stream you get from `stream()` is a concrete implementation of `Stream`, namely some subclass of `ReferencePipeline`. You can't instantiate an interface. This is basically a question about how interfaces work...

Comment: Because it is more or less an `interface`?

Comment: you can just take a look at any of the `stream()` method implementations, can be done in a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
abstract class ReferencePipeline<P_IN, P_OUT>
    extends AbstractPipeline<P_IN, P_OUT, Stream<P_OUT>>
    implements Stream<P_OUT>  ...
```

It's `ReferencePipeline` that implements them. For example:

```
@Override
public final boolean anyMatch(Predicate<? super P_OUT> predicate) {
    return evaluate(MatchOps.makeRef(predicate, MatchOps.MatchKind.ANY));
}
```

Comment: Thank you,friend! I found ReferencePipeline<P_IN, P_OUT> in the jdk source. But strangely it's not found on the official java api doc in Oracle's website.

Comment: @xuange It's not documented there because it isn't public.